# Xcode 9 - High CPU usage - Fan max speed

Tags: xcode, performance, cpu, xcode9

Ever since I upgraded to Xcode 9, my fan goes crazy when I'm working on Xcode. This is especially happening when I use Storyboards and Interface Builder.

Xcode sometimes takes up to 100% of the CPU and the process named "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" is also very greedy.

I read here and there that other people have had similar issues but I was wondering if anyone found a solution to this considering it's most likely a Xcode bug.

Things I've tried:

- Unplugging my second screen: no effect
- Rebooting Xcode: no effect
- Rebooting Mac: no effect
- Cleaning Derived Data folder: no effect
- Cleaning project: no effect
- Opening only 1x project at the time (annoying): a bit better but still not great

**Did anyone find a solution to this issue?**

**Mac Config:**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
- Processor: 2,5 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

**Xcode version:** 9.0 (9A235)

Comment: I filed a bug report about this issue. "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" even stays at 100% CPU if I close the project (not Xcode). It helps somewhat to split the storyboard using "Refactor to storyboard...". Please file a bug report too.

Comment: same here. energy impact of 130, fan at full speed 10 minutes at a time, and all this without compiling, just writing in the editor. Restarting xcode keeps it down for a few minutes, then it's back. No correlation found so far

Comment: Allright, Xcode->Preferences->General->Show live issues = NO. Seems to fix it in my case.

Comment: @codrut - thanks for sharing this tip, I will test that :)

Comment: Talk about celebrating prematurely. It also takes off 10 seconds after I **add a new class** to the project. Xcode restart fixes this case. Will add new triggering use cases to this thread as they occur.

Comment: yeah I also had a mini victory feeling when I tried what you suggested but it didn't last long, haven't found a solution yet. Glad I have 16GB of RAM which makes it manageable but still not ideal.

Comment: I've noticed overheating and unusual fan activity with IB on Xcode 9, but no serious failures.  However, starting with Xcode 9.0.1, I have one storyboard file will open fine with Xcode 9.0, but loops forever when trying to open with Xcode 9.0.1. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922321/xcode-9-0-1-interface-builder-100-cpu-opening-ios-storyboard  Might be a dup, but can't say at this point.

Comment: My storyboard will still not open with Xcode 9.1 (9B55).  Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool still shows 99% CPU and continued Memory leaking even after the project is closed. Fails regardless of the setting for Show Live Issues.

Comment: This question is very likely a dup of another question.  For a possible workaround, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922321/xcode-9-0-1-interface-builder-100-cpu-opening-ios-storyboard/46993736?noredirect=1#comment81088809_46993736

Comment: Appears fixed in **Xcode 9.1 (9B55)**

Comment: I am on Xcode 9.1 and running into the same issue, same specs as Edouard. @EdouardBarbier - did you ever fix this?

Comment: @enlightenedOne I just upgraded today, I'll update this thread when I had some time to use Xcode for a bit to try things out.

Comment: @enlightenedOne well no improvements on my end. I am working on an old project, refactoring a bunch of things, I have about 10 storyboard files on this project but I'm not touching them, just touching code files. But still, the fan is going crazy every time I build & run.

Comment: @EdouardBarbier - thanks for confirming. Same here, to the point where my Xcode is unusable even when writing code. I am restarting it every hour to go around the problem. The funny thing is - this is a new project, with single storyboard and 5 view controllers so far :)

Comment: @enlightenedOne yeah it's crazy, I'm trying to not use storyboard at all for now, writing all UI in code instead to see if it makes any difference. For projects with old storyboards in it; no impact. I'm yet to start something from scratch so let's see.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? I work mobile and this is causing my MacBook Pro's battery to drain in less than 2 hours.

Comment: @Can Poyrazoğlu the only thing that really works for me is to not use Storyboards altogether. I'm starting to really enjoy building everything in code, it's a shame Apple pushes us away from Interface Builder but ... can't do anything else right now.

Answer (score 9):

Open your xibs/storyboards and turn off “Editor / Automatically refresh views”.

The issue is caused by Xcode continually rebuilding your project to update things like custom `IB_DESIGNABLE` views.

***Trigger it manually*** via `Editor > Refresh All views`

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. How do you manually refresh your interface once you've turned this off?

Comment: @Bill: you can trigger it manually via `Editor > Refresh All views`

Comment: Update, I have turned off "Automatically refresh view" but I still get this from time to time.