# Xcode 9.0.1 Interface Builder 100% CPU opening iOS Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, macos-high-sierra

Last night Xcode automatically updated to Version 9.0.1 (9A1004). Today, I tried to open an existing project and my iOS storyboard file gets stuck with a never ending spinner and Activity Monitor reports Interface Builder using 100% CPU. I have a second MacBook Pro that still has Xcode 9.0.0 and it opens the storyboard without any issue.  I'm running macOS High Sierra on both.  Anyone else seen this or know of a workaround.

Comment: This is a possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633160/xcode-9-high-cpu-usage-fan-max-speed?rq=1  However, my storyboard file opens fine on 9.0 but loops forever on 9.0.1.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple and they have since requested that I send them my failing storyboard file and also the output from a utility that analyzes the loop. The ball is now back in their court.  BTW, in my case, activity monitor shows a significant memory leak in conjunction with the loop.

Comment: I just filed a bug report with apple too.  With screenshots and exact steps to reproduce the issue. I hope the workaround I found also works for you but I won't be surprised if apple have multiple bugs.

Comment: My storyboard will still not open with Xcode 9.1 (9B55).  Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool still shows 99% CPU and continued Memory leaking even after the project is closed. Fails regardless of the setting for Show Live Issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I received a response from my bug report with a suggested workaround. The suggestion was to edit the storyboard text and change the value for the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints attribute from NO to YES in the applicable toolbar tags in the storyboard.

From:

```
<toolbar opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill"
 fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KCx-9L-amg">
```

To:

```
<toolbar opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill"
 fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="YES" id="KCx-9L-amg">
```

I have two storyboard files in my project and this does solve the problem with both of them.

Comment: I don't have the <toolbar> tag, what should I edit :), I won't change all 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' to YES right ?

Comment: same here, no `toolbar` tag in my storyboard :/

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to file a bug report and send them the information that they will need to give you a workaround that works for you. When I did, they came back right away and asked:
Please attach the following: 
• A .storyboard document that reproduces this issue. 
• Output from running `sudo spindump Xcode -reveal` in Terminal while the issue reproduces.

Answer (score 8):

I FOUND A FIX!! I have been struggling with this for WEEKS and it has been SO frustrating. Tonight I had an epiphany! From what I have noticed and read, the issue seems to be caused by a massive amount of over-building, particularly if you have IBDesignables in your storyboard like I do. So I thought, 'what if I use Apple's new build system they announced this summer?'

In Xcode, go to **File > Project Settings**. Then change the Build System from "Standard Build System" to "**New Build System**". Voila! It has been working just like it used to! Hopefully it is not just a temporary fix like some of the others I have seen. So far it seems amazing.

I also am using Xcode 9.0 as an extra precaution that I downloaded from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Thank you a lot! Interface Builder Process has 5-10 % of CPU !

Answer (score 5):

Use your storyboard **Vary Traits** concept and set your device in the storyboard to iPhone X.

This is the quick fix in Xcode version 9.1.

[image]

Comment: As I am using XCode 11.5 , I had to set the device iPhone 11 in storyboard. Seems like the highest iPhone you have to select.

Comment: Seems like different devices need different CPU do render. On XCode 13.0 my CPU varies from 30% to 100+% just depending on the Device View which is set.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem.  I have MacBook Pro and iMac both running High Sierra. Just like you I only upgraded on one of my computers (MacBook Pro).  I have tried everything and nothing work.  I even reinstalled the OS and copied the old Xcode from the iMac.

Update:
I have found out how to fix it :-)  I created a new storyboard and put everything in bit by bit until I found the problematic code. I found out that **systemItem="trash"** was the problem.  Then I went to the original storyboard and deleted **systemItem="trash"** and everything works!

I also tried to use **add** and its also failed.  So open the src code for the storyboard and search for systemItem.

**Any image** in Bar Item will get Xcode stuck.  I just tried to replace the system item icon with my own trash icon and again ...

[image]

[image: picture of bar button item]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is neither a fix nor a workaround for me. My storyboard has 29 scenes with 18 systemItems that have images so it would be very awkward to test.  Your analysis is very good. I hope your information will help Apple to provide a quick fix to this problem. I just hope I don't need to edit my storyboard before they make the fix available. Thanks.

Comment: No worries.  Sorry its no good for you.  For me it's a big relief as I can keep working on my GUI now.  I only had systemItems in 3 places and replacing with word is OK for me.  I will let you know as soon as I hear back from Apple

Comment: I think there is more at play here than merely a Bar Button Item with a system image. I can create a simple single view storyboard with a Bar Button Item on both a Nav bar and Toolbar and it does not fail.

Comment: Apple just got back to me saying its a duplicate bug and closed my bug.  However I cannot see the other bug so I have no idea on status :-/

Comment: I was having this same problem.  I didn't have any translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in my storyboard but I did have two flexibleSpace barButtonItems in a toolbar.  I commented them out for now and that fixed the issue for me.  I'm using Xcode 9.1.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Xcode 9.2 Beta 2 (9C34b) and for me its possible to work again :)